# retrieve other fields of a SObject after a user has selected an option

Tags: sobject, aura, iteration

I am writing an app that will help calculate the statute of limitations for certain laws. ex. enter a date that a crime happened on and, after choosing a law and appropriate limitation the limitation time will be added to the date you entered giving the date the limitation is up on.

I have an aura iteration that iterates through some of my statutes for the user to choose. to help the user pick I display a description of the statute in the drop down options, {!stat.Description__c}. then below that I would like to show the user the actual time limit associated with their choice. But I cant find a way to show the user anything different than the label I display in the select options. code below

**component:**

```
<!-- Select Statute -->
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="dropStat" label="Select statute if multiple based on description" class="dynamic" change="{!c.onStatChange}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.statute}" var="stat">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!stat.Description__c}" label="{!stat.Description__c}" />        
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

The statute of limitation is:

```
<ui:outputText value="{!v.statNum.Limit__c}"/>
```

**controller:**

```
onStatChange : function(component, event, helper){
    var selected = component.find("dropStat").get("v.value");
    console.log('selected statute is', selected);
    component.set("v.statNum");
}
```

note that the data types of v.statute and v.statNum are both SObject
Thanks in advance! Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

did this with a for loop

Js Controller: (yes I know I should have probably put this in the helper)

`onStatChange : function(component, event, helper){
        var selected = component.find("dropStat").get("v.value");
        let statObject = component.get("v.statute");
        for(let i=0; i < statObject.length; i++){
            if(statObject[i].Description__c == selected){
                component.set("v.statNum", statObject[i].Limit__c)
            }
        }
    }`